# how to print documents as jpg

Tags: c#, image, printing

My application has to take multiple documents such as .doc, .docx, .pdf, .ppt, .pptx and convert them as jpeg(any other format is also fine) images. if there are multiple pages, each page should become one jpeg.

I tried with some virtual printers but did not work out well.

My app is in C# 2.0

Anyone has a better solution??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google search [found this program](http://www.softinterface.com/Convert-Document-To-Image/Convert-Document-To-Image-T.htm?gclid=CJeVroqPqaICFRkJ3wodT0-ORw). It has a commandline interface so you can call it from .Net using the `Process` class.